# Use of 'as for'

Tags: grammar

The sentence is

> The twins in question were Annabelle and Clarabelle Wiggett, two pixielike young blondes who also lived in the house, known as much for their thick Norwich accents and incessant giggling as for the catastrophic messes they left.

Were the girls laughing at the mess they made or does it mean to say the girls always laugh at the mess they make.

I dont understand the usage of 'as for' in this sentence.

Comment: No. They were famous for two contrasting things: known as much for X as (they were known) for Y.

Comment: The girls were known (i.e. had a reputation amongst others) for making messes.  And for their speaking accents.  And for giggling.

Comment: _as for_ is not a constituent here. It's part of the coordinating equative construction _as much for X as for Y_ using equative _as...as_ (the equivalent of comparative _more...than_). The second _as_ is required by the construction, and the second _for_ phrase modifies _were known_, ljust ike the first one.

Comment: Thank you John Lawler

Answer (score 3):

It means they were known for both their "thick Norwich accents and incessant giggling" and "the catastrophic messes they left" equally; Not known more for one and less for the other one.
"As much as" format is used when we want to make comparisons referring to quantity.